# How to template this kind of function?

Tags: c++, templates

Its a part of a sorting algorithm, I started out like this

```
inline void cmp2(float* a, float* b, int ia, int ib, int &ra, int &rb) {
    if (a[ia] > b[ib]) ra++;
    else rb++;
}
inline void cmp3(float* a, float* b, float* c, int ia, int ib, int ic, int &ra, int &rb, int &rc) {
    if (a[ia] > b[ib]) cmp2(a, c, ia, ic, ra, rc);
    else cmp2(b, c, ib, ic, rb, rc);
}
inline void cmp4(float* a, float* b, float* c, float* d, int ia, int ib, int ic, int id, int &ra, int &rb, int &rc, int &rd) {
    if (a[ia] > b[ib]) cmp3(a, c, d, ia, ic, id, ra, rc, rd);
    else cmp3(b, c, d, ib, ic, id, rb, rc, rd);
}
```

and then I thought "but hey, I could totally do this as a recursive template function". I started over

```
inline void cmp2(float* a, float* b, int ia, int ib, int &ra, int &rb) {
    if (a[ia] > b[ib]) ra++;
    else rb++;
}

template <int n>
inline void cmp(float** data, int* i, int* r) {
    if (data[0][i[0]] > data[1][i[1]]) cmp<n - 1>( ??? brain crash
}
```

I was going to specialize n = 3 to call cmp2 directly and the rest go for cmp< n - 1 > but then I realized that i would have to create a new array of data and iterator arrays every time it splits which would really hurt the performance.

In my case n is variable and can go up to ~10, is there a way to template it so it would run just as quick as if I were to write it out by hand and gather the funcion pointers into an array?

Comment: Isn't this a lot simpler then what you're doing? This looks like you're simply finding the "index" (a=1, b=2,...) of the largest value and incrementing the corresponding variable (`ra`, `rb`,...)

Comment: well yes, bad example I guess, this is not the actual algorithm. I tried to simplify it down to the simplest thing I could think of while keeping the problem for the purpose of this this post

Comment: recursing through variadic templates is useful when you want to pick off some arguments on the head or tail, and the same logic should happen at each recursive step. It looks like your code performs conditional argument passing of some non-contiguous sequence of the arguments that would be in the pack, so I'm not sure that variadic templates would be the best approach. If it were possible, it'd be unreadable and probably require a lot more code than what you've written.

Answer (score 0):

You could use **variadic templates** (C++11 required).

An example with *print* (strings only):

```
#include <iostream>

void print(const std::string& s)
{
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

template<typename... Args>
void print(const std::string& s, Args... args)
{
    std::cout << s;
    print(args...);
}

int main()
{
    print("a", "c", "b");
    return 0;
}
```

You would unpack 2x pointer+index, do your comparison and pass the second and remaining arguments further until you reach the tail which is your cmp2.

Comment: Would you mind to demonstrate how to apply variadic template to modify OP's functions, rather than merely mentioning the existence of the language feature?